# drag UI element by user in UWP

Tags: xaml, uwp, drag-and-drop, uwp-xaml, drag

I have a grid that includes a TextBox. I want to user can drag TextBox in That Grid. I tried canDrag property to set True but It does nothing.

```
<Grid AllowDrop="True">
    <TextBlock CanDrag="True"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/24/uwp-how-to-implement-drag-and-drop-functionality-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how can I control manipulation by keyboard key?
i couldn't limit area. I try the Canvas but it Can't limit area.

actually, we could use everything for an area not only canvas.
i do this in XAML

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="300">
        <TextBlock Text="mahdi" Name="t" ManipulationMode = "TranslateX, TranslateY, Scale"  

    ManipulationDelta = "t_ManipulationDelta" >

            <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                <CompositeTransform x:Name="t_Transform" />
            </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
        </TextBlock>



</Grid>
```

and in c#

```
namespace Manipulation
{
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }




    private void t_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.t_Transform.TranslateX += e.Delta.Translation.X;
        this.t_Transform.TranslateY += e.Delta.Translation.Y;
    }


}
```

}
But i couldn't to limit area. i try the Canvas but it Can't limit area.

Comment: Oh, a `Canvas` will not inherently limit the area, you are right. What a `Canvas` does do, however, is gives you a coordinate system to work with. if your end goal is to use the keyboard, maybe instead of using manipulations, place your `TextBlock` on a `Canvas`, and then handle the key pressed events for the keys you want. When the key is pressed, change the `TextBlock` location on the canvas in the direction of the key pressed.

Comment: I have multiple textbox not only one.

Answer (score 4):

`CanDrag` refers to drag-and-drop functionality, such as dragging and dropping an image file into an image editor. This is different than simply moving the control around on the app.

A child control (in this case textblock) cannot be moved around freely inside of a grid. You need to add a canvas control. A canvas control automatically expands to fill its parent, so it will automatically expand to fill the grid.

You are probably looking for "Manipulation", not "Drag and drop". You will need to handle the `ManipulationStarted`, `ManipulationDelta`, and `ManipulationCompleted` events for the TextBLock:

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas>
        <TextBlock ManipulationStarted="TextBlock_ManipulationStarted"
                   ManipulationDelta="TextBlock_ManipulationDelta"
                   ManipulationCompleted="TextBlock_ManipulationCompleted"></TextBlock>
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

Take a look at the "BasicInput" sample, for how to work with manipulations: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples.

Comment: that's it I was looking for.

Comment: how can I limit area? move in the special area?

Comment: You can limit the area by limiting the size of the `Canvas` the `TextBlock` is being manipulated on. If you do not want it to take up the full `Grid`, simply layer layout controls to get the desired size. You could set the height and width of the `Canvas`, or add rows or columns to the `Grid` and put the `Canvas` in one of those. If you want to freely place the `Canvas` in the `Grid`, you could even put it on another `Canvas`.

Comment: we need RenderTransform and CompositeTransform for Manipulation.